# Way to reuse Entity for Native Query that returns all data but excludes some columns

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity / Table and is being used as the default return type of the repository. But when I make a native query that retrieves all data in the table but does not include some columns. I am encountering an error that says the specific column should be supplied.

This is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'column4' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
```

This is the sample repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TableRepository extends CrudRepository<TableEntity, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TableEntity> findAllWithExcludedColumns();
}
```

This is the sample entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "table")
public class TableEntity {

    @Column(name= "column1")
    private String column1;

    @Column(name= "column2")
    private String column2;

    @Column(name= "column3")
    private String column3;

    @Column(name= "column4")
    private String column4;
}
```

I intended to not include column4 to improve performance of retrieving the contents of the table (blob data)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity table create a constructor with the attributes you are selecting in the query

Comment: I tried to create constructor in the entity table but still returns error: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'column4' not found

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of your query method. findAll.. of findAllWithExcludedColumns() is a keyword for queryDSL. So remove the keyword 'findAll' and it will work.

Comment: I tried to change the method name but still doesnt work. Still returns the same error : java.sql.SQLException: Column 'column4' not found